# How to make a whiteboard/flanelboard style promotional video for a mobile app?

Tags: video

I want to make an animated video which shows what my mobile app can be used for. What are the most economically-conservative resources I can use?

Comment: You may also find [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10685/are-there-technical-issues-with-doing-video-reviews-of-software/10686#10686) relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what kind of animations you're looking for, but **Adobe After Effects** is very popular for animation. You can even get a free 30-day trial of the software. That being said, if you're not familiar with After Effects, there is quite a bit of a learning curve, but the good news is that there are a ton of online resources (videos/tutorials/etc.) to show you what you need to do to get great results.

Comment: Actually I want to make videos which are very similar to video on this page http://www.refiral.com/